# Find the remainder when $x^{100}$ is divided by $x^8 - x^6 + x^4 - x^2 + 1.$

Tags: polynomials

I need help in the problem:

Find the remainder when $x^{100}$ is divided by $x^8 - x^6 + x^4 - x^2 + 1.$
I have tried factoring $x^{100}-1$ and adding 1 to that, but that hasn't helped. Could someone please help with this?

Comment: Hint: note that $x^{10}+1=(x^8-x^6+x^4-x^2+1)(x^2+1)$.

Comment: When I woke up this morning that product was $x^{10}+1$.  What changed?

Comment: Thanks, edited.

Comment: Luckily we got that within the 5-minute window, thanks!

Comment: So we know that $(x^{10}+1)^{10}$ is divisible by $x^8−x^6+x^4−x^2+1$. How does this help for $x^{100}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x^{100}-1=(x^{10}+1)(x^{90}-x^{80}+x^{70}-x^{60}+x^{50}-x^{40}+x^{30}-x^{20}+x^{10}-1)$

$=(x^8-x^6+x^4-x^2+1)(x^2+1)(x^{90}-x^{80}+x^{70}-x^{60}+x^{50}-x^{40}+x^{30}-x^{20}+x^{10}-1)$,

so $x^{100}=$

$(x^8-x^6+x^4-x^2+1)(x^2+1)(x^{90}-x^{80}+x^{70}-x^{60}+x^{50}-x^{40}+x^{30}-x^{20}+x^{10}-1) + 1.$

Answer (score 2):

Hint

Replace $x^2$ with to find the divisor $$=\dfrac{y^5+1}{y+1}$$

$y^{50}=(y^5+1-1)^{10}=1+$ terms divisible by $y^5+1$

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand. Replace $x^2$ with ___. Was that a typo, or what?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I solved it, and it was using a combination of the hint answer I got and the hint in the comments.

I can write $x^{100}$ as $((x^{10}+1)-1)^{10}$. What it expands into is 11 terms, where the first 10 terms all have at least one factor of $(x^{10}+1)$, which factors as: $x^{10}+1=(x^8-x^6+x^4-x^2+1)(x^2+1)$. This means that only the 11th term matters, which is $-1^{10}=1$, giving the answer of $1$.